# ASP.NET Core ViewComponent's Invoke() method call not recognized

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core RC2 app with VS2015 I have following Invoke() method in the ViewComponent class but intellisense is not recognizing the Invoke() method. The app builds successfully but when running it I get the following error:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent]
```

**The Invoke() method in ViewComponent class**:

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string filter)
        {
            var res = (from p in ctx.Product.ToList()
                       where p.ProductName.StartsWith(filter)
                       select p).ToList();

            return View(res);
        }
```

**The Invoke() method call from a view that generates the above error**:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">@Component.Invoke("ProductList", "D")</div>
```

Comment: There is an announcement of changes in the ViewComponent at GitHub Announcement repository. Did you read/consulted it? https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/145. Specifically in the discussion issue at https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3973#issue-128269062

Comment: According to it you need to call it like `@Component.Invoke("ProductList", new { filter = "D" })`

Comment: @Tseng This works. Thank you for pointing to the link about the changes related to `Invoke` method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an old question but I wanted to provide an answer for the 1.0 RTM version of ASP.NET Core.

```cs
@await Component.InvokeAsync("ProductList", new { filter = "D" })
```

`Component.Invoke()` has been removed. So, this is the right way to do it even if the method in the view component is still defined as `Invoke()` (and not `InvokeAsync()`)—which might be alright depending on what the method does.

As an alternative, you could also use the more strongly-typed version...

```cs
@(await Component.InvokeAsync<ProductList>(new { filter = "D" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

- What packages version are you using in the project?
- What's the target framework?
- What's the environtment?
- What web server/listener are you using?
- Check if the Component's view is correct, and have the correct model (at **/Shared/Component/ComponentName/Some.cshtml**)

Try use Async instead of sync component call (Actually I don't even have sync invocation)

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string filter)
{
   var res = await (from p in ctx.Products
                       where p.ProductName.StartsWith(filter)
                       select p).ToListAsync();

            return View(res);
}

@await Component.InvokeAsync("ProductList", "D")
```

I don't actually know if this code works or even compile (I don't use EF)

If the exception is still the same, try update .net core to RTM (preview2-003...) And update the packages to the latest versions.

[Here](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.io/projects/mvc/en/latest/views/view-components.html) is the doc for View Components

Comment: Add more description to your answer.